# JSF page initialization using GET

Tags: java, jsf, get

I need to be able to grab a user's information from a database and pre populate some fields on the page from this information, using args sent in a GET request in the database's query.

What is the best way of performing this "on page load" type of functionality using standard JSF?

Couple possibilities I have found so far:

- performing the initialization in
  the backing bean constructor *(not a huge fan since I'd be making database calls from the constructor)*
- Using a phase listener

Comment: I think this  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-be-jsf-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-for/6377957#6377957 is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (If I am guessing correct what you are trying to accomplish) is

1. When the user logs-in you create a backing bean with his/her information. Thus the DB code is in the action method that holds the login business logic.
2. Whenever you need this information in *any* jsf web page you just inject this info bean to the backing bean behind your page using the normal injection mechanism of **faces-config.xml** for backing beans.

With this approach you do not need a phase listener, and the DB code is not in a constructor of a backing bean but in an action method (as it should).